# There is a real number $\alpha >1$ such that $\Bigl\lfloor2^{2^{{.}^{{.}^{{.}^{2^{\alpha }}}}}}\Bigr\rfloor$ is prime for all $n\geq 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**Theorem:** There exists a real number $\alpha >1$ that if

$$\alpha =\alpha _0,\quad 2^{\alpha _0}=\alpha _1,\quad \dots\quad 2^{\alpha _n}=\alpha _{n+1},\quad  \dots$$

then for all $n\geq 1,\left[\alpha _n\right]$ are prime numbers.

In other words, there exists a real number $\alpha >1$, such that for all $n\geq 1$, $$p_n=\left[2^{2^{{\mathinner{\mkern2mu\raise1pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu \raise4pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7pt\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}^{2^{\alpha }}}}\right]$$ are prime numbers.

I translated the words 'Miller' from Chinese (translated from Russian). How can I find material related this theorem from other books or wiki?

Related: Weierstrass, Bertrand, Chebyshev

Is it related to the [Miller-Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)?

Comment: Help me edit the horizontal dots in $p_n$ to ascending dots?

Comment: The programme I use to code gives $$ {\mathinner{\mkern2mu\raise1pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu
 \raise4pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7pt\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}} $$ with `{\mathinner{\mkern2mu\raise1pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu
 \raise4pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7pt\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}` There must be a better way.

Comment: This is most certainly not related to the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Comment: The proof in my text is not hard(long), maybe you can give a proof too.

Comment: In [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Number-Theory-Second-Mathematics/dp/048646931X/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1373424531&sr=1-3&keywords=elementary+number+theory) there is an entire chapter devoted to proving this (quite straightforward, I might add) and deriving similar types of formulas. Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) for a related formula. Just remember that with these types of formulas, their purpose is defeated by their construction; to actually build the list of generated primes requires knowing the primes you seek in advance!

Comment: It is perhaps meant "Lucas-Lehmer-test" instead of "Miller-Rabin-test". For the Lucas-Lehmer and the question of Mersenne-primes I've seen this discussed occasionally in the web; I think Chris Caldwell has something about this at his prime-pages which goes back to Joerg Arndt; my own fiddling with the version of the Lucas-Lehmer-test (if that was actually meant) is possibly overcomplicated but you may find it at http://go.helms-net.de/www/math/expdioph/lucasLehmer.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This follows from Bertrand's Postulate (proved by Chebyshev): if $p$ is prime, then there is a prime between $2^p$ and $2^{p+1}$ and hence you can choose some $p<x<p+1$ such that $\lfloor 2^x\rfloor$ is prime. Repeat this as often as needed.

See for example [A051501](https://oeis.org/A051501).